# Asymptotic normality

Tags: self-study, least-squares, asymptotics

How can I get the asymptotic normality of the unbiased estimator
$\sigma_2$ so that it is equal to $ e'e/(n-k) $, that is $\sqrt n $ ($\hat \sigma_2$  - $\sigma_2$) $\rightarrow  N (0,v)$ and give the asymptotic variance $v$.

I know that the error term is i.i.d and the fourth moment exists, i.e. $E(\ e_i^4 ) < \infty $

The regressor matrix has full rank. The regressors are deterministic.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Rewrite the expression as
$$\sqrt T(\hat\sigma^2 - \sigma^2) = \frac{\epsilon'\epsilon - T\sigma^2}{\sqrt T} - \frac{1}{\sqrt T}\epsilon'P\epsilon$$
where $P$ is the projection matrix. One can show that the second term goes to zero in probability by using the (general) Chebyshew inequality. The first term converges to $N(0,\mu_4-\sigma^4)$ by CLT where $\mu_4$ is the fourth moment of $\epsilon$.

Comment: Understood. But how can you show each step necessary  to make it a formal proof. I am not good with that.

Comment: 1) first term = $\frac{1}{\sqrt T}\sum(\epsilon_t^2 - \sigma^2)$. The summands are iid with mean zero and variance $\mu_4 - \sigma^4$ (try to calculate this on your own, it is not very difficulat; just apply mean and variance)
2) Apply CLT to first term (in 1)
3) For the second term, use chebyshev inequality or (maybe easier):secon term = $\sqrt T(\hat\beta-\beta)(\frac{1}{T}X'X)(\hat\beta-\beta)$. The last term goes to zero in probability, middle term to some constant and $\sqrt T(\hat\beta-\beta)$ converges in distribution to normal. Thus, the whole expression goes to zero in probability.

Comment: Why is it a T? Should be n, or?

Comment: Where does the $\ beta $ come from?

Comment: Ah yes, you are right, it's an $n$. I used a different source than in the original answer, sorry about that. I edit the original answer.

Note that: $\epsilon'P\epsilon = \epsilon' X(X'X)^{-1}X'\epsilon = \big((X'X)^{-1}X'\epsilon\big)'(X'X)\big((X'X)^{-1}X'\epsilon\big) = \big((X'X)^{-1}X'X\beta + (X'X)^{-1}X'\epsilon - \beta\big)'(X'X)\big((X'X)^{-1}X'X\beta + (X'X)^{-1}X'\epsilon - \beta\big) = (\hat\beta - \beta)'(X'X)(\hat\beta - \beta)$.